# Is this note in Chopin's Nocturne Op. 9, No. 1, a Bb or an Ab?

Tags: piano, editions

In the original edition of Chopin's Nocturne Op. 9, No. 1, there is an Ab in bar 5 (6 if the anacrusis is counted) as the 4th note of the left hand:

[image: Original edition - showing a figure with: D-flat, F, D-flat, A-flat, F, F]

---

However, [somebody6's transcription on MuseScore](https://musescore.com/user/122383/scores/169484) shows a Bb in that place:

[image: Transcription from MuseScore - showing the same figure as above but with a B-flat instead of an A-flat]

Is it correct to play the Ab or the Bb? If I open up the piano keyboard on that bar, I see that the 4th note lines up with a Bb key:

[image: Synthesia keyboard viewer showing a B-flat in the figure.]

---

Rubinstein's recording plays the Ab:

---

**Is this a mutated note? Is it correct to play the Ab or the Bb?**

Comment: Why would you assume an random edition by some random person on MuseScore.com to be in any way a reliable source? ☺

Answer (score 9):

1. The correct note is Ab. This can be checked by looking at the [editions on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Nocturnes,_Op.9_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)) or the [Chopin Variorum](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/).
2. Anacruses are not counted in the measure numbering.
3. Never trust any edition found on MuseScore.

Comment: Short and sweet.  I checked OCVE at the Chopin Variorum manuscript digitalization project archive, in all 3 first editions ([Paris 1832](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/pageview/77137/), [Leipzig 1833](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/pageview/67736/), and [London 1840](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/pageview/67766/)), **the note is Ab**.  The MuseScore transcriber must have made a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly possible for a professionally produced score to have an error where an amateur score does not, but it's far more likely to be the other way around. Absent any other information, you should generally give more weight to the professional score.

But really, whenever you find a discrepancy between two scores, the more careful approach is to look at more scores. (See Andy Bonner's comments along these lines.) See if you can determine why the discrepancy exists: it might be a simple error; the authoritative source might be unclear; there could be multiple authoritative sources that do not agree with each other; it could be a deliberate "correction" of an authoritative source by some editor, and you might decide to agree with that editor or to disagree.

Now, for the most part, people who post their own editions on MuseScore or similar sites (including https://imslp.org and https://cpdl.org) do not invest adequate time and effort in proofreading. Small errors are common. But some people's care in proofreading falls farther short of adequate than others'!

I would therefore refine Aaron's advice somewhat.  Rather than saying "Never trust any edition found on MuseScore," I would say "approach every edition on MuseScore with skepticism" -- but after you've spent time with individual pieces from MuseScore or indeed with several pieces from a given editor, you can form an opinion about the care with which the edition was prepared, and sometimes you will find that some are trustworthy.